# Hide a port from the content-security-policy so that script-src considers the url as self

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy, proxypass, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm setting up the content-security-policy for my site , but the script url for my comments system contains a port number i.e `http://dev.example.com:8080/client.js`.

I have a few other URL's which use ports too and I'd prefer to hide which ports my site uses in case of possible security implications.

How can I hide these URL's containing port numbers so that the CSP considers the URL's as `self`?

For example instead of `http://dev.example.com:8080/client.js` I'd like it to be `http://dev.example.com/comments/client.js`.

I'm on an Nginx server and I've tried playing around with rewriting the URL, but can't get it working.

Here's what I've tried.

This allows me to change the script URL to `http://dev.example.com/comments/client.js`, but CSP still detects `http://dev.example.com:8080/client.js`.

```
  location ~ /comments/ {
    return 301 http://dev.example.com:8080/client.js;
  }
```

Didn't work

```
location ~ /comments/ {
    rewrite ^/comments/(.*) http://dev.example.com:8080/$1 last;
}
```

Just to be clear I know I can just throw the URL `http://dev.example.com:8080/client.js` straight into CSP e.g `script-src 'self'
dev.example.com:8080/client.js;`, but I want the URL to work with `self` e.g `script-src 'self'`.

Returns `502 bad gateway` error

```
location /comments {
    proxy_pass http://dev.example.com:8080/;
 }
```

Also returns`502 bad gateway`.

```
location = /comments {
     return 301 /comments/;
}

 location ~ /comments/(?<ndpath>.*) {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive";
    proxy_store off;
    proxy_pass http://dev.example.com:8080/$ndpath$is_args$args;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types *;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the concept of a reverse proxy. [Described here.](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

In your case the simplest example is

```
location /comments {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
}
```

Comment: I keep getting `502 bad gateway` errors with `proxy pass`. Updated the OP with examples.

Comment: Well you might have to look at firewall setting, etc... because this is a very common scenario that is used a lot.